# Spark: Determine the driver address from within a task

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For debugging purposes, I want to send a message from a spark task (running within an executor) to the driver machine.  The [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking) claim that `spark.driver.host` contains this information, but I don't know how to access it from worker (or from the driver, for that matter...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the driver's IP to the workers via a captured global variable:

```py
import socket
driver_ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

def process_data(data):
    # Do some work ...
    send_log_msg(driver_ip_addr, "hello!")
    # Do some more work...

processed_data = my_rdd.map(process_data).collect()
```

Comment: it is better we broadcast the ip to all worker 
 val broadcastIP= spark.sparkContext.broadcast(ip)  then we can easily get the ip by 

val ip = broadcastIP.value.get(ip).get

Answer (score 3):

```
sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")
```

but driver is not what you need. You need a worker. So try something like this code inside your rdd.mapPartitions block:

```
val localhost = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost
val ip = java.net.NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localhost)
```

check [this](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/get-current-ip-addresses-scala) for a more precise approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My question was badly worded (sorry about that; now the question is fixed) -- I want the worker to know the *driver* IP.  But I see now that there's a very simple solution: Just broadcast the driver IP to the workers with a broadcast variable (or a global constant in Python).  I think I have a solution.